# API Platform multi schema postgresql

Tags: symfony-3.4, api-platform.com

I am currently working on a project which must be able, dynamically, to be able to connect on different diagrams according to the connected user.

I am using symfony 3.4 and api_platform.

To achieve my goals, I thought I would intercept the execution of requests with a subscriber or an event listener and modify the ORM diagram (if possible).

Have you ever encountered this problem?

Do you think this is possible this way? or do you have an idea of ​​how to do it differently?

Thank you